# Is undefined a subtype of null in typescript?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, null, undefined

I am reading the typescript handbook and came across the following code.

```
declare function create(o: object | null): void;
create({ prop: 0 });
create(null);
create(undefined); // Remember, undefined is a subtype of null 
Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object | null'.

create(42);
Argument of type '42' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object | null'.
create("string");
Argument of type '"string"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object | null'.
create(false);
Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object | null'.
```

Note the comment on line 4 saying `Remember, undefined is a subtype of null`.

If thats the case, why on the next line does it throw the error `Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object | null'.`.

Why cant I assign a subtype to it's base type. Is there a typo. Thanks

Comment: Probably it should be _undefined is **not** a subtype of null_

Comment: Ok. Submitted a pull request.